# How to add a warmup time for ecs tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am using ecs tasks to deploy my services. However, recently noticing that when I do an update on the service, the first task that starts up usually gets taken down immediately because it fails load balancer health checks. I think this is because it needs more time (a second or two more) to startup. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 1):

When updating the ECS Service with a new [Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html), I'd suggest also setting the `healthCheckGracePeriodSeconds` parameter. See [Service Definition Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html) for more details.

If you're using the cli, you should be able to do this with `aws ecs update-service --cluster <value> --service <value> --health-check-grace-period-seconds <value>`.

If for example, your HealthCheck interval is 30 seconds, and 2 unhealthy checks will cause the service to be replaced, but you know your service takes, say 65 seconds to start up, you could set `--health-check-grace-period-seconds 95`, and this would tell ECS even if the service is considered unhealthy, let it keep going until 95 seconds would pass. I chose 95 in this case because the next healthcheck would be expected to come at 90 seconds, so if I did less than that, the load balancer may not notice the service is healthy before the unhealthy check takes effect.